# Background-image not showing with CSS

Tags: html, css, background

Can't figure out why the background image is not showing... Used / and \ , short and long path... Any cue would be appreciated. Thanks

```
<head>

<title>Restaurant Lambda</title>

<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>


<body>
<!--Menu-->
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="topnav">
                    <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
                    <a href="#news">About</a>
                    <a href="#contact">Ingredients</a>
                    <a href="#contact">Menu</a>
                    <a href="#contact">Reviews</a>
                    <a href="#contact">Reservation</a>

            </div>
                </nav>

    </header>


</body>
```

```
.countainer {
    background: url("C:/Users/lili/Desktop/LesManifestesTest/img/Bg.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you share more information about your project folder structure? Usually, the best practice is to have media files (including images) in a subfolder inside your project, and use a relative path instead, something like `background: url(../images/Bg.png)`

Comment: Also, by having the image in your Desktop, your page would not work when you upload your files to some server.

Comment: Typo? `div.container` in HTML, but `.countainer {}` in CSS. There is an additional **u**.

Comment: It does not show up locally.
I have this folder o my desktop named LesManifestesTest which contains a folder img with all images like Bg.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually 3 reasons this might be happening.

1. In the div, it says `<div class="container">` but in your css, you have

```
.countainer {
    background: url("C:/Users/lili/Desktop/LesManifestesTest/img/Bg.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

So you would need to fix the spelling error.

---

2. Put the file and the image in a folder, then link it like

```
.container {
    background: url("folder/imagename") no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

---

3. Fix your formatting

In the code block, you've got `<div>` then `<nav>` but you end with `</div>` then `</nav>` so after reformatting your code, it should look like

```
<div class="container">
        <nav class="topnav">
                    <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
                    <a href="#news">About</a>
                    <a href="#contact">Ingredients</a>
                    <a href="#contact">Menu</a>
                    <a href="#contact">Reviews</a>
                    <a href="#contact">Reservation</a>

        </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as the typo in your class name (the extra 'u' in container/countainer), your syntax is incorrect. You are closing the `nav` **after** you've closed the `div`, instead of the other way around.

Correct these errors, and your image should show correctly (given that your path is correct)

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  background: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/06/30/09/31/background-image-3507320__340.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;
}

nav {
  text-align: center;
}

nav a {
  color: white; /*added for better visibility*/
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!--Menu-->
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="topnav">
        <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">About</a>
        <a href="#contact">Ingredients</a>
        <a href="#contact">Menu</a>
        <a href="#contact">Reviews</a>
        <a href="#contact">Reservation</a>
      </nav>

    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```